# how to create a custom button in android like in the attached picture?

Tags: android, button, view

I want to create a custom button like this picture :

[image]

"Picture" is my picture.

Comment: Please show what you have tried and what the problem is you're running into, so we can better help you.

Comment: Look into [`ImageButton`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html).

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/IM3tn.jpg  1-border 2-Transparency 50%

Answer (score 0):

In general I'd say try the [ImageButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html) class.

Comment: BUT... first he has to set the picture's alpha to 128 (50%). Or he can do that later, by code.

Comment: this is my main view, www.i.stack.imgur.com/IM3tn.jpg 1-border 2-Transparency 50%

Answer (score 0):

All interface objects in Android are children of the [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) class, so any object can act as a button by simply adding an [OnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) to it.  As such, you can create a [ViewGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html) in your XML that looks exactly how you want, then add an onClickListener.

A simple example:

Layout XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bgimg"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/clickableButtonWithBorder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:padding="20dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/centerPicture"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/blue_rect_icon" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and the drawable/border.xml:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
   <solid android:color="#7fffffff" />
   <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#4fa5d5"/>
</shape>
```

Java Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ViewGroup clickableButtonWithBorder = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.clickableButtonWithBorder);
        // set transparency of the background to 50% (127/255)
        clickableButtonWithBorder.getBackground().setAlpha(127);
        clickableButtonWithBorder.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Someone clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

The visual result is this:

[image: button with transparent background]

Comment: I modified to meet your screenshot.  Now has a border via the border.xml